# Is there a way to test if a scalar has been stringified or not?

Tags: perl

I am writing a thing to output something similar to JSON, from a perl structure.  I want the quoting to behave like this:

```
"string" outputs "string"
"05" outputs "05"
"5" outputs "5"
5 outputs 5
05 outputs 5, or 05 would be acceptable
```

JSON::XS handles this by testing if a scalar has been "stringified" or not, which I think is very cool.  But I can't find a way to do this test myself without writing XS, which I'd rather avoid.  Is this possible?  I can't find this anywhere on CPAN without finding vast pedantry about Scalar::Util::looks_like_number, etc which completely isn't what I want.  The only stopgap I can find is Devel::Peek, which feels evil.  And also, just like JSON::XS, I'm fine with this secenario:

```
my $a = 5;
print $a."\n";
# now $a outputs "5" instead of 5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspect the output of [`B::svref_2object`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B#Utility_Functions):

```
use B;
($x, $y, $z) = ("5", 5, 5.0);

print ref(B::svref_2object( \$x )), "\n";
print ref(B::svref_2object( \$y )), "\n";
print ref(B::svref_2object( \$z )), "\n";
```

Output:

```
B::PV
B::IV
B::NV
```

---

Or, as ikegami suggests, if you'd rather lookup the `pPOK` flag:

```
if (B::svref_2object( \$x )->FLAGS & B::SVp_POK) {
    print "I guess \$x is stringy\n";
}
```

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the SV type. It has to do with the pPOK flag.

Comment: For example, look at `my $x=""; $x=5; my $y=5; "".$y;`. Both are PVIV, but only one is "stringy".

Comment: I just noticed that too. It would be nice if B actually listed what it provided! Unfortunately, it seems `SvGETMAGIC` isn't available.

Comment: Really? I get `B::PV` for `perl -MB -E 'my$y=5;say ref B::svref_2object(\("".$y))`. Are you passing a reference to `svref_2object`?

Comment: uh, you're not looking at $y. `perl -MB -E'my$x="";$x=5;say ref B::svref_2object(\$x);'` and `perl -MB -E'my$y=5;"".$y;say ref B::svref_2object(\$y);'`

Comment: Both your answers helped a lot (@ikegami and @mob) so I randomly picked one to accept.  I did a little more research and ended up checking if FLAGS & B::SVp_POK was true.  There are several caveats however, as @ikegami mentioned-- For example, my $a = "5"; $a++; will have SVp_POK true and SVp_IOK false.  However my $a = "5"; $a = $a + 1; will have SVp_POK false and SVp_IOK true.  This is good enough for my purposes though!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You can make it so a number no longer appears to have been stringified by using the following:

```
$x = 0+$x;
```

For example,

```
$ perl -MJSON::XS -E'
   $_ = 4;
   say encode_json([$_]);  # [4]
   "".$_;
   say encode_json([$_]);  # ["4"]
   $_ = 0 + $_;
   say encode_json([$_]);  # [4]
'
```

Detecting whether something has been stringified is tougher because JSON::XS is looking into Perl internals. One could use the following:

```
sub is_stringy {
   { no warnings 'void'; "".$_[0]; }
   return 1;
}
```

but I don't think that's what you want :) I don't know how to detect the "corruption" without writing some XS code. What you want to know is if `SvPOKp` is true for the scalar (after you call `SvGETMAGIC` on the scalar).

```
use Inline C => <<'__EOI__';

   SV* is_stringy(SV* sv) {
      SvGETMAGIC(sv);
      return SvPOKp(sv) ? &PL_sv_yes : &PL_sv_no;
   }

__EOI__

$_ = 4;
say is_stringy($_) ?1:0;   # 0
{ no warnings 'void'; "".$_; }
say is_stringy($_) ?1:0;   # 1
$_ = 0+$_;
say is_stringy($_) ?1:0;   # 0
```

oo! It turns out that [B](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B) does provide `SVp_POK`, so it can (almost) be done in without writing new XS code

```
use B qw( svref_2object SVp_POK );

sub is_stringy {
   my ($s) = @_;
   my $sv = svref_2object(\$s);
   #$sv->GETMAGIC();  # Not available
   return $sv->FLAGS & SVp_POK;
}
```

Being unable to call `SvGETMAGIC` has drawbacks, but it will work almost all of the time.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the best way, but if `JSON` does what you want, why not use it?

```
sub is_stringy {
    encode_json([$_[0]]) =~ /["']/
}

is_stringy(5);      # undef
is_string("5");     # 1
```

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing if I can't find a better answer.  That sure feels wasteful though.  I would just keep the scalar output of JSON::XS, but unfortunately what I'm outputting isn't JSON and has different escaping rules, etc.